# How to add to cart from external site?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, cart, addtocart

I created a landing page on an external site and I want to be able to add to cart from that external site. Is there any hack I can use to do this? Is there a custom URL I can use? I am using Magento 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Magento 2 REST API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/order-tutorial/order-add-items.html)

Add a simple product to a cart

To add a simple product to a cart, you must provide a sku, the quantity, and the quote ID, which was generated when the cart was created.

The following example adds an orange medium-sized Radiant women’s t-shirt (sku: WS12-M-Orange) to the cart.

Endpoint

POST http:///rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items

Headers

Content-Type application/json

Authorization Bearer

Payload

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "WS12-M-Orange",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "4"
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "item_id": 7,
  "sku": "WS12-M-Orange",
  "qty": 1,
  "name": "Radiant Tee-M-Orange",
  "product_type": "simple",
  "quote_id": "4"
}
```